# Xcode organizer doesn't show my device - only my projects

Tags: ios, xcode

I read the answers to other similar questions here and all of them ask to go to the Devices section of the Xcode Organizer page. However, I don't even see the Organizer page. I only see a list of projects.

Can somebody help please? I am using Version 6.1.1 (6A2008a), Developing for iOS using Swift, have a valid iOS developer registration, certificate approved by apple, downloaded and installed in my keychain.

I have an iPad3 connected to my macbook pro which IS recognized by itunes, iphoto, etc.

Thanks much.

ave

Comment: Window > Devices, it is the first menu option above Organizer.

Comment: Thanks, I see that but it doesn't give me the option to "Enable for development". All I see is a list of devices, then when I click on the iPad, it shows me the device info: (Name, Model, Capacity, Battery, iOS, Identifier, then two buttons under it: View Device Logs, Take Screenshot). Under that is a a table of Installed Apps (no apps installed).

Comment: Hi I'm following up after more hunting/experimentation. I simply followed the instructions on the Apple site: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/LaunchingYourApponDevices/LaunchingYourApponDevices.html#//apple_ref/doc/ and it seems that I don't have to do anything more - I was able to select the ipad from the Product->Destination menu of XCode and it just launched on the device. Guess it was already provisioned? Still I'm peeved that there's I had to wade through all this when Apple could've told me "Your device is (already) enabled"

Comment: Good, all you need to do now is to read the message on the phone and decide if you want to Trust the connected Mac.